# How to analyze usefulness of imputation output in R

Tags: r, regression, distributions, mathematical-statistics, data-imputation

I am working with a dataset with 3,500 observations and includes a Body Mass Index variable. There are around 300 NA values for the BMI variable which I have imputed using multiple imputation. Apologies that this is not reproducible, wasn't sure how to do that quickly in this case. Here is the code I used to impute the data.

```
noms=c("REGION_1","REGION_2","REGION_4","SMOKE","MARRIED","NON_WHITE","MOD_SEV_ANX","HYPERTEN",
"DIABETES","BELOW_100_POVERTY", "IMMIGRANT","FEMALE", "EDUC_2","EDUC_3","EDUC_4","EDUC_5"),
             p2s = 0)
a1
imp.mod <- zelig(BMICALC ~ AGE+FAMSIZE+factor(BELOW_100_POVERTY)+factor(IMMIGRANT)
                  +factor(FEMALE)+factor(EDUC_2)+factor(EDUC_3)
                  +factor(EDUC_4)+factor(EDUC_5)+factor(REGION_1)+factor(REGION_2)+factor(REGION_4)+
                   factor(SMOKE)+factor(MARRIED)+factor(NON_WHITE)+factor(MOD_SEV_ANX)+factor(HYPERTEN)+
            factor(DIABETES), model = "ls", data = a1, cite = F)
summary(imp.mod)
```

And here is the output

[image]

From [this website here](http://juliejosse.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/DataAnalysisMissingR.html#inspect_the_imputed_values) I have found information on how to interpret whether the imputation needs more investigation, or whether I can continue to analyze the data using a regression model. I have included the code where I create the 2 visuals per the website's instructions but I am unclear on how to interpret whether the imputation is accurate. Do the two distributions in the first graphic need to be close? Can someone clarify what the y=x line and blue confidence intervals/dots mean in the second image? Is the output here indicative of whether the imputation will suffice to be used in regression analysis? I've attached the code and output below. Thank you!

`compare.density(a1, var = "BMICALC")`
[image]

overimpute(a1, var = "BMICALC") ```
[image]

Comment: great question!!!